# CCAvenue Xamarin android ToolKit

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, ccavenue

Hi every body I need to integrate CCAvenue payment gateway for my Xamarin android project, I am unable to find any sample code to get this.
Any body please provide CCAvenue Xamarin android Tool Kit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

CCAvenue don't appear to officially support or provide sample code for Xamarin, however the integration process is described in their Mobile Integration Toolkit:

https://mars.ccavenue.com/downloads/Mobile_Integraion_Kit.zip

You could re-use (or re-write) the Android or iOS sample code in C#. I wrote an answer which describes at a high level the two methods to which you can integrate with CCAvenue

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30121414/1359646

Answer (score 0):

Ccavenue does not provide the integration source code to enable the payment gateway for xamarin. However there are developers who can write a source code for implementing the ccavenue. Here is one from the official xamarin website.

https://components.xamarin.com/view/ccavenue