# Android CC-AVENUE Payment Gateway Integration

Tags: android, integration, payment, ccavenue

I want to integrate CC-Avenue Payment method in my Android app. I have got some code, but they need an RSA key url. Can anyone help?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990820/android-integration-with-ccavenue

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. Also, please edit your expectations alongside that process. **Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service**. Also, **please** walk away from payment if you do not know your gears. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to download GetRSA.php file from CCAVENUE dashbord(website) and need to put (host) somewhere domain/server and give the path of GetRSA.php file RSA url
for example www.xyz.com/GetRSA.php.
For that purpose you need to give ip address of xyz.com (hosting place ip address) to ccavennue technicale team so thhat they can integrate the that ip

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do in the web view activity is to fetch RSA public key by requesting the page that is kept on your server (the page GetRSA JSP). To fetch RSA public key in app, parameters(accessCode and orderId) are to be sent to the JSP(GetRSA). The GetRSA JSP will then initiate a server to server call to the CCA server with those parameters and will get an RSA public key in response which will be forwarded to the app.