# Android ccavenue payment gateway integration

Tags: java, android, android-studio, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I am trying to integrate Android CCavenue payment gateway integration in my Android Recharge Application

I have followed this link  [followed steps in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990820/android-integration-with-ccavenue) and also CCavenue Document

When i try to click on pay button

[image]

I am getting html document as response from GetRSA.php which is deployed on server like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
     <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
     <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>404 Not Found</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
             font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
             font-size: 14px;
             line-height: 1.428571429;
             background-co
    etc......................
```

Here is my Sample Code:

```
String vResponse = sh.makeServiceCall(mainIntent.getStringExtra(AvenuesParams.RSA_KEY_URL), ServiceHandler.POST, params);
        System.out.println("Response"+vResponse);//printing above mentioned html code
```

Can any one please assist on this

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all html tags from GetRSA.php file.. It will work as expected.